# How to make Python plot windows appear on a different monitor in Spacemacs (emacs)

Tags: python, ubuntu, emacs, spacemacs

In Ubuntu 16.04, I want Spacemacs Python-mode to show plot windows in a specific location on one of my monitors. How can I do it?

Comment: This is more of a window manager feature than emacs or even matplotlib.  Doing it with your window manager or something like `xdotool` is probably the simplest way.  Even if there's a way to do it in matplotlib, the window manager ultimately has control of where windows go.

Comment: can`t you open a new frame in emacs and then just drag it desired location, then run the plot command in it?

Comment: @dre-hh I think that Python plots appear in the independent window from the emacs one

Comment: @jpkotta thanks. I use standart Unity desktop, can you recommend any particular command for which I should look for?

Comment: @Cons: I don't use unity (I've used fvwm for over a decade), so I have no idea.  `xdotool` is window manager-agnostic; I haven't played with it too much.